# Erase shadow of an image in opencv 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm working with license plate segmentation, and I have some images with shadows in the part of the plate that difficult the recognition processing, some idea of erase the shadow in the part of the plate for leave the letters clear. Thanks and appreciate any helps!

Here two images:

[image with shadow2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OecKQ.png)

I want use MSER for detect the letters in the plate and after do a segmentation of it. Firstly I do a preprocess of the image(blur and CLAHE), after  apply a morphological BLACKHAT transformation and after apply the MSER but the recognition isn't good. I think that removing the shadow of the plate the result will be better. I don't know what to do, thanks for your response and Help!!, my code and result is:

```
Mat gray_neg;
Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(5, 5));
morphologyEx(imageLoad, gray_neg, MORPH_BLACKHAT, element);
cv::Ptr<cv::MSER> mesr1 = cv::MSER::create(2, 30, 600, 0.15, 0.2);
std::vector<cv::Rect> bboxes1;
vector<vector<Point> > contours1;
mesr1->detectRegions(gray_neg.clone(), contours1, bboxes1);

Mat image_grayBGR;
    cvtColor(imageLoad, image_grayBGR, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
for (int i = 0; i < bboxes1.size(); i++){
    rectangle(image_grayBGR, bboxes1[i], CV_RGB(255, 0, 0));
}


imshow("MSER", image_grayBGR);
```

the final result is

[MSER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wtuz.png)

Comment: I don't see any problem with the shadows. Please describe what your problem is. Maybe provide some intermediate images and some code...

Comment: I don't understand exactly what is your problem? Do you detect the license plate and have problem with the OCR or you have problem with detecting the plate from the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I complemented my question, I'm using MSER for detect the letters of the plate.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I also don't see any problems with the shadow that would affect the image recognition of the plate. What you will need to do is isolate the letters and numbers on the license plate on each image file by using an image segmentation algorithm of your choice, the shadow and all the other parts of the images should be treated as noise and interference. You could also use thresholding and the Hough transform algorithm in order to assist with the optical character recognition.